# How to bind SQL parameters dynamically?

Tags: php, sql, database, filter

I want to make a website where I can show activities. I want to make a filter function based on location and dates.

I use this query to filter the dates:

```
function selectAllActivities($date = false, $locations = false){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `activities`
            INNER JOIN `locations` ON `activities`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
            WHERE 1";

    if (!empty($date)){
      $sql .=  " AND `activities`.`start` >= :date AND `activities`.`start` < :next_day";
    }
    if (!empty($locations)){

      }

    }
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    if ($date){
      $dateTime = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
      $dateTimeTomorrow= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date.'+1 day'));
      $stmt->bindValue(':date', $dateTime);
      $stmt->bindValue(':next_day', $dateTimeTomorrow);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For the locations I have an array with the selected dates in $locations, but I don't know how to bind the parameters dynamically to the query when the users selects more than 1 location to filter.

This is how I want it hardcoded:

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE 1 AND `location_id` IN (:location_id_0, :location_id_1, :location_id_2)

$stmt->bindValue(':location_id_1', $locations[0]);
$stmt->bindValue(':location_id_2', $locations[1]);
$stmt->bindValue(':location_id_3', $locations[2]);
```

I think I need to use the foreach function, but I can't really figure out how.

Comment: @Qirel Yes it comes in as an array

Comment: I noticed so from the last code-snippet just after commenting, therefor I deleted the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two simple foreach loops like this:

```
if (is_array($locations)) {
    $placeHolders = [];        
    foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
        $placeHolders[$key] = ':location_id_'.$key;
    }
    $sql .= ' AND `location_id` IN ('.implode(', ',$placeHolders).')';
}

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

if (is_array($locations)) {
    foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
        $stmt->bindValue($placeHolders[$key], $location);
    }
}
```

When `$locations` is not empty you loop through its array. Using the `$key` of that array you create a `$placeHolders` array for your MySQL query.

After that you prepare the statement.

Then you bind the locations to the statement using the `$placeHolders` array.

Comment: By using this, you finish generating the query in `$sql` *after* you have already bound the values, so you need to separate the creation of query and bindings, using the same condition - but different stages of the execution.